# Emacs: Startup with no window system

Tags: linux, emacs

I know to start emacs with no window system, I do:

```
emacs -nw filename.txt
```

But, I don't want to specify -nw constantly. What do I add in my .emacs to do this automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on platform in shell, I believe you could add an alias in your bashrc or bash_profile (depending on needs) so that emacs is interpreted as emacs -nw

Comment: I think this answer is as good as it is going to get.  I ran an experiment of setting the variable 'window-system to nil as the only thing done in the .emacs file and then started emacs from a terminal.  As expected, it had no effect.  As an alternative to using an alias, one could use a script (emacs.sh or emacs.bat) instead of invoking the executable directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to install the non graphical version of emacs, under OSX I have the package "emacs @23.2, Revision 5 (editors): installed via MacPorts so when I type 'emacs' it never shows a GUI. off course aliasing (as suggested in another answer) leaves you with the option to run the graphical version sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your `~/.bash_profile` and put this in a new line:
   `alias emacs="emacs -nw"`
2. Save the file.
3. Applying the change *everywhere* and *immediately* is simplest if you just log out and then log back in.

Answer (score 1):

As a slightly more extensive example ...

*Here is a snippet from my local .bashrc*

```
  ## grrrr me type bad
    alias emasc='emacs -nw'
    alias emacs='emacs -nw'
    alias emacsx='emacs23-x'
    alias ls='ls --color'
```

That does it for me.

Also if your using emacs in a "real" console it detects the absence of a windowing environment and starts correctly without an alias .

i.e.

```
ctrl + alt + F[1-6]
```

You could also set your EDITOR env variable (in bashrc)

Finally you could uninstall any GUI versions :)

on debian:

```
apt-get install emacs23-nox
```

would most probably do it all for you.